# how to fetch a value from a database related to dropdownlist in php

Tags: php, mysql, database, drop-down-menu

plz help to solve this problem.
The $query1 & $query statements are not giving proper o/p.
$query1 is showing o/p as-->**Resource id #5**
**The error is-->Undefined variable: hname in C:\xampp\htdocs\Programs\hosp.php on line 30**

*My question is:*
**Write a PHP script which accepts hospital name and print information about doctors visiting working in that hospital in tabular format.**

*My database is:*
**hospital(hid,hname)
doctor(did,dname,hid) //here hid is a foreign key**

The program which I have written:-

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php $PHP_SELF;?>">
Select Hospital Name:<br>
<?php
$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root');
if (!$con)
{
    die("Could not connect..".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('employee');

$sql = "SELECT hname FROM hospital";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='hname'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='" . $row['hname'] ."'>" . $row['hname'] ."</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
<br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
<?
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //echo "Selected value: $_POST[hname]";
    $hosp = $_POST['hname'];
    echo "Hosp Name: $hosp";
    $query1=mysql_query("select hid from hospital where hname='$hname'");
    //$query1=mysql_query("select hid from hospital where hname='{$_POST[hname]}' ");
    echo $query1;
    $query=mysql_query ("SELECT did from doctor where hid='$query1' "); 
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
    {
        $did=$row['did'];
        echo $did;
    }
}
?>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $hname = $_POST['hname'];

    //First query
    $query1 = "select hid from hospital where hname='".$hname."'";
    //echo $query1;
    $result=mysql_query($query1);    
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $hid = $row['hid'];
    //echo $hid;

    //second query
    $query2 = "SELECT did from doctor where hid=".$hid;
    //echo $query2;
    $result2=mysql_query($query2);    
    $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $did = $row['did'];
    //echo $did;    
}
```

**Things to note:**

- Avoid SQL injection
- Use PDO or mysqli extensions

Comment: Thanks for your response.. :)

But still the error is coming at this line:

echo $query1;

It shows its value as-->Resource id #5

In query1 I want the hid from hospital table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate help.. It works absolutely fine.. Thanks.. Have a great day ahead.. :)